# iPhone UIWebView stringFromJavaScript with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, uiwebview

I'm looking for a way to include the jQuery javascript library in my project so I can use

```
[myWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:a jquery command];
```

This doesn't work:

```
NSString *jQueryPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"jquery-1.4.1" ofType:@"js"];
NSData *jQueryData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:jQueryPath];
jQuery = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithData:jQueryData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *javaScript = [jQuery stringByAppendingString:@"$('#ct100_mainContent_hypEmbGamerTag img').attr('src');"];
NSString *returnValue = [theWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:javaScript];
```

I think it has something to do with the way Objective-C handles the / character.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

A bit late coming I know, but the easiest way would be to include the jQuery library via a  tag on the page if possible.

I'm having problems with the ajax calls screwing up sometimes after user interactions on the UIWebView though.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  What page are you referring to?  I was wanting to apply a JQuery to a webpage that I didn't have control of editing.  Like "Download page from XYZ Server, apply this JQuery logic to it."